# Android Marshmallow noHistory="true" misbehavior

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

Everyone knew that in Android 6.0 Marshmallow exist a new Permissions mechanism.

When I start to integrated this mechanism, I noticed that all activities in my apps, that contains flag `android:noHistory="true"` doesn't works properly.

What happens? `ActivityCompat23Api` - class that executes a requesting mechanism, launches new Activity, and requested activity(Activity with `noHistory` flag) automatically finished, due to `noHistory` flag sense. So all activities which contains flag `noHistory` will be finished, when Android show permission dialog.

I want to know any workaround or any possible scenario to keep my activities works, without removing `noHistory` flag.

Comment: instead of using noHistory, I'm just calling the next Activity using some flags.  If you set the intent with these flags:  setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  then the new activity starts and clears the stack and ALL previous history.  I only needed it for an initial download in my splash page, but it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Use `finish()` when you do not need the Activity to be in the stack. It will solve the problem.